# How to test a jpa readonly query?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The model is simplified for the question.

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Formation {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String login;
    String code;
    String level;
    // geters and Setters
```

With this repository:

```
public interface FormationRepository extends JpaRepository<Formation, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT UNIQUE l.id, l.login, d.code,d.level\n" 
        "   FROM          table_login l,\n" +
        "                 table_diploma d,\n" +
        "   WHERE         
        "                 l.fhab_key = d.fhab_key\n" +
        "   AND           l.login= :login", nativeQuery = true)
List<Formation> findAllByLogin(@Param("login")String login);
```

So far so good, this works.

Now I want to add test for the repository (with and h2database). But I can't save data, as the entity isn't mapped to a single table.

So this won't work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class FormationRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    FormationRepository formationRepository;

    @Test
    public void communeRepositoryTest() {
        Formation formation = new Formation();
        formation.setId(123L);
        formation.setDlog_login("123");
        formationRepository.save(formation); // ok
        formationRepository.findAllByLogin("123"); // ko -> Caused by: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: scolarite.scol_droit_login is not mapped
    }
}
```

Here I need to add, that I don't want sql files in my app.

So what would be a solution here ?

Change my model to create an entity by table ? (in real, my request use 8 inner joins, so it will be quite long to code all that...)

Another solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to create the entities for all your tables, you could pre-populate your testing H2 database by defining `schema.sql` and `data.sql` on your classpath.

- **schema.sql** will contain the DDL statements to create all tables involved (you mention 8 tables).
- **data.sql** will contain the insert statements needed to make your custom sql return login = 123.

You can find an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql).

Then your test code would be like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class FormationRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    FormationRepository formationRepository;

    @Test
    public void communeRepositoryTest() {
        List<Formation> formations =  formationRepository.findAllByLogin("123"); 
        Assert.assertEquals(formations.size(), 1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid sql files. Mainly because, it's a pain to maintain sql and entities, when jpa can take care of it. But maybe that's is the most 'reasonable way' of doing it...